# CM ticket response surveys are missing inputs

Tags: bug, email, contact

I filed a contact ticket recently. Once it was responded to, I received a survey asking me for my feedback on the response.

Unfortunately, the radio buttons in that feedback response did not have text attached, and the “is there anything else we should know about?” question had no text field to fill out, so I cannot fill out the form. Honestly I'm happy with how it was handled, but I'm not able to say so.

> [image: "are you satisfied with how your agent handled your inquiry?" - two blank radio buttons to pick from]

This occurred in Firefox Focus (latest) for Android.

I tried to see if this would also happen in Chrome for Android, but when I tried to open it there I was told the link had expired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! I did some testing and turns out the survey is not mobile friendly. If you're on a PC, mousing over the radio buttons will change color and display a simple yes or no.

Also, the “is there anything else we should know about?” question is the text box. Clicking into it will allow you to fill it out.

Basically, I've learned that Freshdesk surveys aren't great. Luckily this was just a short experiment to test them out. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I actually tap the controls I see the yes/no green/red highlights and that the rectangle thingy is the input box itself. That definitely isn't super mobile friendly, oof! Thank you for investigating. Even on desktop though I'd expect radio buttons to have text before I mouse over them — looks like someone got a bit too creative with the form controls. :P